# Downloading PDF blob not working for old browsers

Tags: javascript, blob

I am trying to write code that downloads blob as pdf for all the browser. 
I am using following code for the same. The code works fine for the latest chrome and chromium but fails in an older version of chromium.

```
 var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if (product && product.toUpperCase() == 'a') {
        http.open("POST", someURL, true);
    }
    else {
        http.open("POST", someURL, true);
    }
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    http.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    var blob = window.Blob || window.mozBlob || window.web;
    http.onload = function (e) {
        var contentType = http.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');
        if (e.currentTarget.status == 200) {
            console.log(e.currentTarget.response);
            try {
                blob = new Blob([e.currentTarget.response], { type: 'application/pdf',encoding:'raw' });
            }
            //backward compatibility
            catch (error) {
                window.BlobBuilder = window.BlobBuilder || window.WebKitBlobBuilder || window.MozBlobBuilder || window.MSBlobBuilder;
                if (error.name == 'TypeError' && window.BlobBuilder) {
                    var blobBuilder = new BlobBuilder();
                    console.log(e.currentTarget.response);
                    blobBuilder.append(e.currentTarget.response);
                    blob = blobBuilder.getBlob('application/pdf');
                }
            }
        //    window.saveAs(blob,"abcd.pdf");
            var downloadUrl = (window.URL ? URL : webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);
                 var a = document.createElement("a");
            //IE support for blob ,as it gives exception
            if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
                $(a).click(function () {
                    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, title + '.pdf');
                });
            }
             if (('download' in a)) {
               // Chromium browser and the chrome version is greater than 20
               // Chromium version>20
                a.href = decodeURIComponent(downloadUrl);
                a.target = '_blank';
                a.download = title + '.pdf';
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                // setTimeout(function () {
                //     a.click();
                //     document.body.removeChild(a);
                // }, 66);
                // a.href = decodeURIComponent(downloadUrl);
                // a.target ='_blank';
                // a.download = title + '.pdf';
                // document.body.appendChild(a);
                if("click"  in a ){
                    a.click();
                }else if("dispatchEvent" in a){
                    console.log('in dispatch event ');
                    var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
                    evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
                        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
                    console.log(evt);
                    a.dispatchEvent(evt);
                }
```

for the particular version of chromium that I am testing in download, attribute is supported, but click() function isn't supported in it. 
I tried to use dispatch event to trigger click on the link, It does not flash any error but does nothing.
I have also tried using FileSaver.js but that isn't working out for me.

Thanks in advance!!1

Comment: take a tour to mdn https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Blob and look compatibity browsers

Comment: The issue doesnt seem like blob incompatibity as I am getting correct arraybuffer object

Comment: Why do you even use arraybuffer ? You know you've got `responseType = 'blob'` for *almost\** same compatibility ? (*chrome users stuck between v10 and v19 must be really rare) [_edit_] I now read that HTMLElement#click was not supported on `<a>` before chrome v20, so indeed a chrome version between 14 and 19 might need an arraybuffer and wouldn't support the `click` method. But don't do your tests like that. chrome is easily updatable. If you need to test older browsers, do it on older OS (e.g inside an VirtualMachine)  and test latest browsers available there.

Comment: The problem is .it is an application built in chromium and cannot be updated...so versions between 14 and 19 are giving a tough time..I used response type blob as well but I got empty response with this particular version..the thing I am finding wierd is the dispatch event isn't working for me..what I read is it works nearly for all versions..any thoughts??